# php array iteration & concatenate

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like the one below, I would like to check if the next elem starts with a space, if it does, concatenate it to the previous elem.

```
[1] => Array (
    [1] => lenny/volatile/main Packages
    [2] => lenny/volatile/main Packages
    [3] => lenny/volatile/main Sources
    [4] =>  Reading package
    [5] => lenny/volatile/main Sources
)

Output:

[1] => Array (
    [1] => lenny/volatile/main Packages
    [2] => lenny/volatile/main Packages
    [3] => lenny/volatile/main Sources Reading package
    [5] => lenny/volatile/main Sources
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$count = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if($array[$i][0] == ' '){
        if($i > 0){
             $array[$i-1] .= $array[$i];
             unset($array[$i])
        }
    }
}
```

That should do it (that is if your array is named `$array`, otherwise suit it to your needs)

Comment: He doesn't want items that start with a space to be eliminated; he wants them appended to the previous item.

Comment: Note that `count` is being run on every iteration. Might be worth storing that in a variable somewhere, or even using a `foreach`, since you're using both the key and value, anyway. \*shrug\*

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it checkout the [PHP demo](http://codepad.org/uCrE595e):

```
//your starting array
$myarray = array("lenny/volatile/main Packages","lenny/volatile/main Packages", "lenny/volatile/main Sources", " Reading package", "lenny/volatile/main Sources");

$mystring = implode(",", $myarray);  //implode array into a string delimited by ,
echo $mystring.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;  //debug

$mystring = str_replace(", ", ' ', $mystring); //str replace all ", " with ' '
echo $mystring.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL; //debug

$result= explode(',',$mystring);  //explode back into an array with delimiter ','
print_r($result);  //should give you final result
```

output result @Michael:

```
lenny/volatile/main Packages,lenny/volatile/main Packages,lenny/volatile/main Sources, Reading package,lenny/volatile/main Sources

lenny/volatile/main Packages,lenny/volatile/main Packages,lenny/volatile/main Sources Reading package,lenny/volatile/main Sources

    Array
    (
        [0] => lenny/volatile/main Packages
        [1] => lenny/volatile/main Packages
        [2] => lenny/volatile/main Sources Reading package
        [3] => lenny/volatile/main Sources
    )
```

Comment: Cute :) Raw iteration is probably significantly faster, but I like the simplicity.

Comment: @matchu i like less lines ;D thanks.  made it cleaner w/ comment

Comment: I might be looking wrong but the explode would do nothing right, you just removed all , by a single space. I guess you want to replace ",  " with ", " (double for single space)

Comment: @Michael the explode just pretty much make it back into an array w/ delimiter set as `,` so basically you concatinate the `$mystring` elements and then `explode` it back to an array and out put it like what the poster want as the final result (an array).

Comment: @kjy seems to work but I'm missing something here, aren't your removing all , in the string with the str_replace?

Comment: @Michael i remove `", "` not `","` so that way it will only remove element with first char as space and thus concat element with leading space with previous element.

Answer (score 1):

@manitor you forgot to add the value to the previous line bfore deleting.

should read like that:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    if($array[$i][0] == ' '){
        $array[$i-1].= $array[$i];
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This creates a new array the way you want it:

```
$target = array(array_shift($array));
$to = 0;
foreach($array as $string) {
    if($string[0] === ' ') {
        $target[$to] .= $string;
    }
    else {
        $target[] = $string;
        $to++;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/ajMzS5pm)

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested code but it might get you on the right track. I would iterate over each one in the array. If it is cool add it to the new array. If not concat it to the previous node. I added a pointer so that your index will remain packed in the new array.

```
//$my_array already full of stuff
$new_array = array();
$pointer = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($my_array); $i++) {
    if($i == 0) {
        $new_array[$pointer] = $my_array[$i];
    } else {
        $string = $my_array[$i];
        if(substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - 1) == ' ') {
            $new_array[$pointer - 1] .= $string;
        } else {
            $new_array[$pointer] = $string;
        }
    }
    $pointer++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried something exotic here just for fun ;) tried to use a minimal amount of lines to get it working.

Array:

```
$myAr = Array(
    0 => "lenny/volatile/main Packages",
    1 => "lenny/volatile/main Packages",
    2 => "lenny/volatile/main Sources",
    3 => " Reading package",
    4 => "lenny/volatile/main Sources",
);
```

Function call & logic (will drop the string is there is no previous item)

```
array_walk($myAr, 'concat', &$myAr);

function concat($item, $key, $ar) {
 if(preg_match("/^(\s+)(.*)/", $item, $matches) == 1) {
   unset($ar[$key]);
   if (isset($ar[--$key])){
     $ar[$key] .= $matches[0];
   }
 }
}
```

Result:

```
var_dump($myAr);

array(4) { 
  [0]=> string(28) "lenny/volatile/main Packages" 
  [1]=> string(28) "lenny/volatile/main Packages" 
  [2]=> string(43) "lenny/volatile/main Sources Reading package" 
  [4]=> string(27) "lenny/volatile/main Sources" 
}
```