# php array iteration - unset

Tags: php, arrays

Back to my original question, on how to check if the next elem starts with a space, if it does, concatenate it to the previous elem. how would you deal with cases where the array has multiple levels.

```
[1] => Array (
    [1] => Packages
    [2] => Sources
    [3] =>  Reading package
    [4] =>  Sources
    [5] =>  More Sources
    [6] => volatile Sources
    [7] =>  volatile
)
```

To output:

```
[2] => Array (
    [1] => Packages
    [2] => Sources Reading package Sources More Sources
    [6] => volatile Sources volatile
)
```

Will do it for the first space.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    if($array[$i][0] == ' '){
        if($i > 0){
             $array[$i-1] .= $array[$i];
             unset($array[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Iterating over an array and changing it is wrong!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278119/php-array-iteration-concatenate

Comment: So this is actually a duplicate?

Comment: Don't create a new question, clarify your original one instead.[@kjy112 already provided a working solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278119/php-array-iteration-concatenate/5278205#5278205) to your original question.

Comment: @Felix i am pretty sure the question was solved, but not sure if OP knows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$t = array ( 'Packages',
             'Sources',
             ' Reading package',
             ' Sources',
             ' More Sources',
             'volatile Sources',
             ' volatile'
           );


$n = '';
foreach($t as $k => $v) {
    if (substr($v,0,1) == ' ') {
        $t[$n] .= $v;
        unset($t[$k]);
    } else {
        $n = $k;
    }
}

var_dump($t);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (untested) :

```
$size = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
    $space = true;
    for($j = $i + 1; $j < $size && $space; $j++) {
        $space = $array[$j][0] == ' ';
        if($space){
             $array[$i] .= $array[$j];
             unset($array[$j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure that a particular character (e.g. `|`) is not present in any of your elements, you can do something like this:

```
$array = explode('|',str_replace('| ',' ',implode('|',$array)));
```

Comment: Don't I at least get cool points for getting it all on one line?